# Generic curry arrow functions gets types error in TS

Tags: typescript, generics, currying

This function divides string into three parts.

```
transform<T extends String, N>(arr: T): T {
let length = arr.length;
const split = (fn: (i: N) => T) => (p: (q: N) => N) => (arg: N) => fn(p(arg));

const param = (arg: number): number => {
  if (length % 3 === 1) {
    arg = 1;
  } else if (length % 3 === 2) {
    arg = 2;
  }
  return arg
}

const func = (index: number): string => {
  let divided = [];
  let first = arr.slice(0, index);
  let lastQuery = arr.slice(index);
  for (let i = 0; i < lastQuery.length; i += 3) {
    divided.push(lastQuery.slice(i, 3 + i))
  }

  let res: string[] = [first, ...divided];
  return res.join(' ');
}
return split(func)(param)(0);
}
```

**TS2345: Argument of type '(index: number) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(i: N) => T'.
Types of parameters 'index' and 'i' are incompatible.
Type 'N' is not assignable to type 'number'.**

**TS2345: Argument of type '(arg: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(q: N) => N'.
Types of parameters 'arg' and 'q' are incompatible.
Type 'N' is not assignable to type 'number'.**

**TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'N'.
'N' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'number'.**

*T is string, N is number.*

*I misunderstand why have this errors, anyone can help?*

Comment: Why are you using generics here?

Comment: `T extends string` means that `T` can be any *subtype* of `string` that the *caller* wants, including a string literal type like `"hello"`.  Similarly, `N` can be any type the caller wants (although perhaps you want it constrained to `N extends number`).  If you want `T` to *be* `string` and `N` to *be* `number` then you don't need generics at all.  Indeed, the [non-generic version of your code](https://tsplay.dev/wOGKpw) looks fine to me.  So why are you trying to use generics at all here? Can you articulate what purpose they are supposed to serve?

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are seeing are TypeScript type errors, indicating that the types of some of the arguments and return values in the `transform` function do not match the expected types.

The first error message, `TS2345: Argument of type '(index: number) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(i: N) => T'.`, indicates that the type of the `func` parameter `(index: number) => string` does not match the expected type `(i: N) => T`. Here, `N` is a generic type parameter, which means that it can be any type, not necessarily `number`. Therefore, TypeScript cannot guarantee that the return type of `func` (which is `string`) matches the expected return type `T` (which could be any type). One way to fix this error is to make `T` more specific by constraining it to be `string` like so: `transform<T extends string, N>(arr: T): T`.

The second error message, `TS2345: Argument of type '(arg: number) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(q: N) => N'.`, indicates that the type of the `param` parameter `(arg: number) => number` does not match the expected type `(q: N) => N`. Similar to the previous error, `N` is a generic type parameter, and TypeScript cannot guarantee that the return type of `param` (which is `number`) matches the expected return type `N`. One way to fix this error is to cast the return type of `param` to `N` like so: `const param = (arg: number): N => { ... }`.

The third error message, `TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'N'.`, indicates that the literal value `0` passed as an argument to `split(func)(param)(0)` does not match the expected type `N`. This error occurs because TypeScript cannot guarantee that `N` is `number`. To fix this error, you can either change the type of `N` to `number`, or cast the value `0` to `N` like so: `split(func)(param)(0 as N)`.